# Is there a way to get the url the client was on when a request was sent

Tags: express, sails.js

I'm trying to get the url of the page a client was on when requestion the manifest.appcache file.

I tried

> var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;

but i get the url of the file requested when I do that (localhost:1337/manifest.appcache)

What I want is something like localhost:1337/mushroom/
or localhost:1337/gingerbread/ ie the page that the user was on when the request was sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Referer` HTTP request is what you are looking for.

Instead of using `req.originalURL`, use `req.get('referer')`

From MDN web docs: ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer))

> The Referer request header contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed. The Referer header allows servers to identify where people are visiting them from and may use that data for analytics, logging, or optimized caching, for example.

I use this on my sites to redirect users back to the page they were on after they login.
Happy coding!

Comment: I figured as much, unfortunately i was trying to access it when the file requested is the manifest and apparently the referer is empty by specifications at that point